# scrape dynamic content in python from https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how to scrape dynamic content in beautiful soup or any other library for tags
`<use xlink:href="#icon-verified"></use>` and `<span data-test="answer-box-thanks-value">21</span>`

Unable to access these using beautiful soup

```
# <span data-test="answer-box-thanks-value">19</span>
r=requests.get('https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148')
r=r.text
# print("Terima kasih" in r)
bsoup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
for span in bsoup.find_all('span',{"data-test":"answer-box-thanks-value"}):
    print(span)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the page, you see that the data is under `"upvoteCount":21`.

Try the following the get the correct upvote count:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

result = re.search(r'"upvoteCount":(\d+)', str(soup)).group(1)
print(result) # Output: 21
```

Comment: how do I get the green verification button on the web page?

Comment: @AbhishekVerma Well, its an svg icon, what are you meant to scrape exactly?

Comment: its color and text to the right of it "Jawaban terverifikasi ahli"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366657/scrape-text-in-python-from-https-brainly-co-id-tugas-148