# scrape text in python from https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

scrape "Jawaban terverifikasi ahli" in green box from the url https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148, possibly the color of green tick icon to the left of it also(tag `<use xlink:href="#icon-verified"></use>`)

code

```
from pydash import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get('https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148')
r=r.content#text
bsoup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
for xlink_href in bsoup.find_all('use'):
    if xlink_href.has_attr('xlink:href'):
        print(xlink_href)
        icon=get(xlink_href,'xlink:href')
        green=(icon=='#icon-verified')
        if green: 
            print('verified found ',green)
#<use xlink:href="#icon-verified"></use>
l=bsoup.find_all('h3')
print([i.text for i in l])
#<h3 class="sg-headline">Jawaban terverifikasi ahli
```

output

```
<use xlink:href="#icon-search"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-messages"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-points"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-check"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow_left"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow_right"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow_down"></use>
<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow_up"></use>
['Pertanyaan baru di Biologi', '\nTentang kami\n', '\nBantuan\n', '\nDapatkan App Brainly\n']
```

not able to get #icon-verified use tag and "Jawaban terverifikasi ahli" from h3 tag

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: Please provide the expected MRE. Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect. We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have updated the question with codes and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG icon data is loaded dynamically, we can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = "https://brainly.co.id/tugas/148"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe") 
driver.get(URL)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('h3', class_='sg-headline').text)
print(soup.find(id='icon-verified').find('path'))

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Jawaban terverifikasi ahli
<path d="M458.68 177.07l-51.58-25.6-8.93-53.33a24.5 24.5 0 0 0-26.66-19.2l-55.99 8.53L275 49.07a22.52 22.52 0 0 0-31.45 0l-44.66 38.4-55.98-8.53a23.1 23.1 0 0 0-26.93 19.2l-8.93 53.33-51.45 25.6a23.92 23.92 0 0 0-11.2 29.86L71.08 256 46.8 305.07a25.59 25.59 0 0 0 8.94 29.86l51.45 25.6 8.93 53.34a24.6 24.6 0 0 0 26.92 19.2l55.99-8.54 40.25 38.4a22.37 22.37 0 0 0 31.32 0l40-38.4 55.98 8.54a23.1 23.1 0 0 0 27.05-19.2l8.93-53.34 51.46-25.6a21 21 0 0 0 8.93-29.86L443.08 256h-.13l24.66-49.07a25.77 25.77 0 0 0-8.93-29.86zm-112.17 48.76L256 316.34a21.4 21.4 0 0 1-30.17 0L165.5 256a21.33 21.33 0 1 1 30.17-30.17l45.26 45.25 75.42-75.42a21.33 21.33 0 0 1 30.17 30.17z"></path>
```